# Why setDate() is giving the final date in milliseconds in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, datetime, gmt

I a trying to save a date to the nextMonth. For that I am first setting the month to next 30 days. But the final output date it is giving me in milliseconds.
I want the date in GMT format strictly.

What can I do for that?

```
var snm = new Date();
snm = snm.setDate(snm.getDate() + 30);
                console.log("snm = "+ snm);
```

Comment: @appleapple no. OP the thing is you're using the date in an expression. If you want the date as a string, use `.toLocaleString()` or another similar API. Also, if you want to go to next month, it'd make sense to call `.getMonth()` and add 1.

Comment: you shouldn't need to reassign `snm`. `snm = snm.setDate` seems wrong here

Comment: Understand that a Date instance is not "in" any particular format other than a Date instance. Converting the date to a string by any means is how any formatting is achieved, but it has nothing to do with the intrinsic nature of the object.

Comment: The *set* methods return the modified time value, not the Date the method was called on. You must do it in two steps: `snm.setDate(snm.getDate() + 30); console.log(snm.toISOString());` or you can create a new Date object (wasteful, but not much): `new Date(snm.setDate(snm.getDate() + 30)).toISOString()`.

Comment: Oh, GMT isn't a format, it's a timezone. Perhaps you meant ISO 8601 format like "2021-01-28T23:56:08.062Z".

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
var snm = new Date();
snm.setDate(snm.getDate() + 30)
console.log("snm = "+ snm.toString());
```

Comment: I want in GMT format like this: Tue Jan 26 2021 13:14:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: changed the code...use the above

Comment: Code–only answers aren't helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.